# How to set all selected file absolute paths/names by JFileChooser into a JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I have this small application with a `JButton` to open a `JFileChooser` to select multiple files. So when I click its `approve button` I should be able to set all the selected files' absolute paths or names into a `JTextField`(in my case it's `jTextField1`).

**I know how to do this if I have selected only 1 file, but not with MULTIPLE SELECTED FILES**

How can I do this???

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    JFileChooser copy = new JFileChooser();
    copy.setApproveButtonText("Copy");
    copy.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
    copy.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
    int copyDialog = copy.showOpenDialog(null);
    File[] files = copy.getSelectedFiles();
    if (copyDialog == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        if(files.length>=2){
            jTextField1.setText(files.toString()); // I need to set jTextField1's text with all the selected file paths or names
        }else{
            jTextField1.setText(copy.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath().toString());
        }
    } else {

    }
}
```

Comment: Calling `toString` of an array doesn't do what you would expect it to. Try `java.util.Arrays::toString` instead.

Comment: Can you give me an example or something helpful? @M.Prokhorov

Comment: Sure, example: `java.util.Arrays.toString(new Object[] { "a", "b", "c"})`.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can collect and join the files with a stream:

```
Arrays.stream(files)
        .map(File::getAbsolutePath)
        .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
```

This would join the paths by a linebreak. You can change your delimiter to your need. In that case there is no need for your `if(files.length>=2)`

If it is not possible to use java 8 you can create a method creating the complete string:

```
private String getPaths(File[] files) {
    if (files == null || files.length == 0) {
        return "";
    }
    StringBuilder paths = new StringBuilder();
    paths.append(files[0].getAbsolutePath());
    for (int i = 1; i < files.length; i++) {
        paths.append('\n');
        paths.append(files[i].getAbsolutePath());
    }
    return paths.toString();
}
```

Comment: There is no method called **stream()** regarded to `Arrays`

Comment: @user7980830 It comes with [java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-T:A-)

Comment: Sir, can you please provide a solution for earlier versions of Java? That would be a great help.

Comment: "sir"... ok :) I edited the answer so you can `jTextField1.setText(getPaths(files))`

Comment: Thank you very much :) Saved my day ^_^